# How can one create hanging indent within text?

Tags: formatting

Short of writing a highly specific function for particular text strings, is there a simple way to format text, as say in a bibliographic record, to produce a hanging indent (first line of full with, second and subsequent lines indented) as in a style option?

I find nothing via an online search or within the *Mathematica* documentation concerning hanging indentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `TextCell` with the option [`ParagraphIndent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParagraphIndent.html)

```
TextCell[StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}], 900], "Text", 
 ParagraphIndent -> -40]
```

[image]

or  `Style` with the option [`LineIndent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LineIndent.html):

```
Style[StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}], 900], "Text", LineIndent->2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can mark any cell you like, invoke OptionInspector for it and go to FormattingOptions>TextLayoutOptions. There you find ParagraphIndent and TabSpacings.

E.g. ParagraphIndent -120  and TabSpacings {7.65} leaves enough space before the hanging paragraph e.g. for an outdented ISO date (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) - but only if you display with 100%. If you display it with 125%, the tab no longer aligns with the ParagraphIndent. The reason seems to be that ParagraphIndent is defined in printer's points. TabSpacings is in "ems", a strage unit apparently related to the width of a capital M, which of course grows larger if the display maginification is increased.